# Ambiguous tag [machine]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request, ambiguous-tags

Uses of [machine](/questions/tagged/machine) include

- [virtual-machine](/questions/tagged/virtual-machine)
- [jvm](/questions/tagged/jvm)
- [machine-learning](/questions/tagged/machine-learning)
- [state-machine](/questions/tagged/state-machine)

Questions tagged [machine](/questions/tagged/machine) should be edited and retagged with one of the more specific tags.

Comment: This probably is a tag that needs to be blacklisted, as it is likely to come back.

Comment: It's now on my list of **54** tags kept dead every day, as blacklisting requires an SE employee, and they don't like blacklisting as a solution to horrible tags nowadays.